# Google Big Query - Creating Temp Tables created Datasets

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am kind of new to BQ and realized much too late that the create temp table query creates a random dataset for the temp table to go into under my project.
I did this under my company's project and now i'm afraid that I created like 50 datasets under it but I can't see them in the list and from my knowledge, datasets created from this query start with "script" or "_script" so I tried searching for this but none of them show up on the list.

I just know our BI team doesn't like for people to be creating random stuff in the project.

HOWEVER I can still see and delete some of them if I go into the table I created. I know the tables will delete and expire automatically but what about the datasets..?

THis may be the most stupid question someone has asked on here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From reading here ... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/multi-statement-queries#temporary_tables .. I am sensing that temporary tables evaporate after 24 hours or can be explicitly deleted.  I also read that they "managed" by BQ.  As such, I would imagine that no-one is going to be concerned by the existence of these "transient" and BQ managed datasets.  If someone questions, point them to the above doc.